# how do i print the element of an array without brackets or quotes?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is driving me crazy. I'm basically trying to check if saved_category_parent matches parsed_category_parent

it says saved_category_parent belongs to class Array, while parsed_category_parent (scraped with nokogiri) says its a string.

So when I try to check the following it always returns false because its comparing **first** with **["first"]**

I just need to remove the stupid brackets. i tried to_s and it actually makes it worse... it adds more parenthesis and more brackets.

```
if saved_category_parent == parsed_category_parent && saved_category == parsed_category
    //code
end
```

heres my other code

```
categories = ["#first > sub-cat", "#second > sub-cat-2"]

# Parse through saved categories and break them up

categories.each do |category|
  saved_category_parent = category.scan(/#([^ ]*)/)[0]
  saved_category        = category.scan(/.* > (.*)$/)[0]

  @rss = Nokogiri::HTML(open(open(link.get_attribute('href'))))

  @rss.css('.col').each do |forumblock|
    parsed_category_parent = forumblock.css('h4 a').inner_text
    forumblock.css('li a').each do |forumlink|
      parsed_category = forumlink.content

      # p saved_category_parent
      # p parsed_category_parent
      # p saved_category
      # p parsed_category

      p saved_category_parent
      p saved_category



    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array only has one element you can do this:

```
# creating the values manually for the example
parsed_category_parent = "first"
saved_category_parent = ["first"]

# solution
parsed_category_parent = saved_category_parent[0]
```

You can try it in IRB to see that it works.

By using the [] operator you are accessing the first element of the array which is a string, thus comparing two strings together rather than comparing a string with an array containing a string.

You could also use other methods of accessing elements in an array like "first".

Comment: close I think. When I put "p saved_category[0]" its still saying ["sub-cat"] ... yet when I use "puts saved_category" it works fine (it just says "sub-cat" without quotes). I have tried both methods with .first and [0] and it still wont return as just a string. Maybe my if is wrong though? say "hello" if saved_category_parent[0] == parsed_category_parent && saved_category[0] == parsed_category

Comment: now that i think about it it seems 'scan' is wrong. I dont want it to be in a new array, i just want a simple string with the result of the scan

Comment: @Tallboy: If you do  p saved_category_parent without the [0], you should get ["first"], while p saved_category_parent[0] should give you "first".

Comment: oops, it works now... weird, i must have removed the [0] on accident before i tried your code. lemme try again

Comment: @Tallboy: Maybe you could do category[/#([^ ]*)/] instead of scan ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#first` to get the first (or only) element of the array:

```
irb> ["first"].first
  => "first"
```